# How to take an input from a form and store a variable in an existing object

Tags: javascript-objects, key-value

I'm trying to take data from a form and add it to an existing Object movieData. I am able to pass all the lower key value pairs in but the title which is a top layer key is not recognised and is passed as a string. Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
let movieData = {
    "The Darjeeling Limited": {
      plot: "A year after their father's funeral, three brothers travel across India by train in an attempt to bond with each other.",
      cast: ["Jason Schwartzman", "Owen Wilson", "Adrien Brody"],
      runtime: 151,
      rating: 7.2,
      year: 2007,
    }
...
}

function handleForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
  const newRating = document.getElementById("newRating").value;
  const newYear = document.getElementById("newYear").value;
  const newRuntime = document.getElementById("newRuntime").value;
  const newCast = document.getElementById("newCast").value;
  const newPlot = document.getElementById("newPlot").value;
  
  var addNewMovie = {
   newTitle : {
      rating: newRating,
      year: newYear,
      runtime: newRuntime,
      cast: newCast,
      plot: newPlot,
    }
  };
        Object.assign(movieData, addNewMovie)
console.log(movieData);
displayMovieData();
    }

form.addEventListener('submit',handleForm);
```

I've tried this but unfortunately newTitle doesn't register and gets passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addNewMovie = {
   [newTitle] : {
      rating: newRating,
      year: newYear,
      runtime: newRuntime,
      cast: newCast,
      plot: newPlot,
    }
  };
```

I realised I needed to add square brackets around the first key/variable.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal/